# MouseClick Event on PyQt Folder Tree

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, file-browser

I have coded out a small application using PyQt5. The application gives a tree view of all folders in the computer plus a lineEditd where the user can type things:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,QWidget,
     QVBoxLayout,QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QLineEdit
)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        application = App()
        layout.addWidget(application)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    
        

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setNameFilters([''])
        self.model.setNameFilterDisables(0)
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.input = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.input)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

My next goal is to make my application able to detect mouse click on the tree diagram. More precisely, in an event of a mouse click on any folder in the tree, I want to know the directory of the folder which the user clicks (so that I can, for instance, update the LineEdit by filling it with the directory)

To achieve such a goal, the first thing I need to do is to make mouse click in the tree an event. If I add a method like:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
    #some code
```

It will not give me an event reflecting the fact that the mouse click happens in the tree. I am therefore stuck on even making mouse click in tree an event, nor to mention reading the directory .

Edit:

By writing

`self.tree.clicked`

I am able to detect any click in the tree. However, I still do not know how to get the directory.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, just use the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal of the tree view. Also, do not call `self.show()` of the child widget (it's unnecessary since it will be added to the parent layout), and just use `self.setCentralWidget(application)`, as the container widget is unnecessary if you're just adding a child widget.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for responding. I have read about the clicked signal and I managed to get clicking on tree as an event. But how do I read the index and actually get the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the directory using the view's clicked signal then you should use the model:

```
self.tree.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)
```

```
def handle_clicked(self, index):
    filename = self.model.fileName(index)
    path = self.model.filePath(index)
    fileinfo = self.model.fileInfo(index)
    print(filename, path, fileinfo)
```